# 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have searched a lot on stackoverflow but not a single solution work in my case.
I want to make a simple Media Player that play audio from raw source. My raw folder size is about 2 GB. When I try to clean and rebuild my project it show error

in Message Gradle Build:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
      com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1. 
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1 mins 54.534 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Where Gradle Console suggests:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task  ':app:processDebugResources'.com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
    org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.owais.surah">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="My Book"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity 
            android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My build.gradle is

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    dexOptions {
          incremental = true;
          preDexLibraries = false
          javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.owais.surah"
         minSdkVersion 15
         targetSdkVersion 23
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
              minifyEnabled false
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),              
             'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
    }

    dependencies {
         compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
         testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
         compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: You should start here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698816/gradle-what-is-a-non-zero-exit-value-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 4):

Cleaning the project will work. Do:

```
Build -> Clean Project
```

This error comes usually when you do some copy-paste work like pasting images, or other assets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Android studio only accepts images within a certain file name frame.
it must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
Try check your drawable

Answer (score 0):

delete all files in the assets folder containing non-english characters in the title