# Android gradle how to exclude specific folder?

Tags: android, gradle

I try to build project but this error occured:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK lib/x86/libjniopenblas.so
    File1: C:\Users\1\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets\openblas\0.2.19-1.3\2189141b6c83cc8e5b342b04e8f49e22996f72f4\openblas-0.2.19-1.3-android-x86.jar
    File2: D:\Smart House\Sip projects\Camera\tipit\build\intermediates\bundles\default\jni
```

How to exclude this directory from build `D:\Smart House\Sip projects\Camera\tipit\build\intermediates\bundles\default\jni`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700213/duplicatefileexception-error-while-building-android-apk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pickFirst in `packagingOptions` to use only one of `libjniopenblas.so` file:

You need to get the correct package name of `libjniopenblas.so` from File1 or File2:

```
android {

    ...

    packagingOptions {

       // This is using the library in File1
       pickFirst 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/openblas/lib/x86/libjniopenblas.so'

       ...
    }

   ...
}
```

But instead of the above, you can using exclude. First, find the dependency which using the `libjniopenblas.so` by checking it from the dependency tree with:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

Then after you found it, exclude it from the library with:

```
compile('com.library.name:version') {
  exclude "libjniopenblas.so"
  // or exclude the module of the library
}
```

Comment: Both variants works fine thank you so much. Even more now I know how to look for duplicate dependencies!:)

Comment: Congratulations! I'm glad that my answer help you ;)