# Process 'command' finished with non-zero exit value

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have developed an android project in android studio, but when I run the project I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

So how can I get rid of this error?

**This is my *build.gradle* file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abc.project1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/mongo-2.10.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-3.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle - What is a non-zero exit value and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698816/gradle-what-is-a-non-zero-exit-value-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: There is not enough information in your question. Please show the **full** error. and your build.gradle file

Comment: updated. please see now

Comment: Updated again. please see now.

Comment: Please see the question that I flagged in the first comment. You do not need `compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')` because it is included already

Comment: this means I should just remove `compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')` from build.gradle, and then the project will run fine?

Comment: Not necessarily. You've also included all of Google Play Services. Please carefully read the additional notes section of that answer.

Comment: I am getting exactly the same error even now by the way @cricket_007

Comment: Yeah, I know. Because you have overlapping dependencies.

Comment: so what should I do, please tell in some detail?

Comment: There is no simple answer to your question. I have already provided all the details you need to find and fix the problem in that other post

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the same dependencies twice.

Remove `compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')` from your build.gradle file.

Also delete the `libs/android-support-v4.jar` from your project (because with   `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` you are adding it again.