# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio

**ERROR**
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

**my gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sagar.shavanma"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}


dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}
```

**Gridle**

:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidVolleyVolley100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubNirhartParallaxscroll10Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug
:app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug
ProGuard, version 5.2.1
Reading program jar [G:\Projects\Shavanma\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Users\shree\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0-preview\lib\shrinkedAndroid.jar]
Preparing output jar [G:\Projects\Shavanma\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar]
  Copying resources from program jar [G:\Projects\Shavanma\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar]
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: What do you have in the libs folder?

Comment: Along with that, you may read this solution.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698816/gradle-what-is-a-non-zero-exit-value-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: @cricket_007-its empty

Comment: Okay, so what does the rest of the error say, then?

Comment: @cricket_007..only single error

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the entire Gradle output. What is before "Error:Execution failed for task"?

Answer (score 0):

try add this in your build.gradle file:
under dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

then create a global application class for your app:

```
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
public class Global_class extends Application {

 protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
   }
}
```

add this class in your manifest file under application tag

```
 <application
    android:name="com.package_name.Global_class"
 </application>
```

Comment: If you don't need multidex, then there's no reason to add it. It also might not fix the problem

Comment: try deleting the app/build folder and then debug, don't add external jar files in your libs folder..clean the project and build it again. Try using stackTrace option when debug