# Error when I build my android project

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I have creer a project with navigation drawer when I build it I have the following error
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: can you please share a bit more of logcat

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I don't like that duplicate. The answers there only serve to address the error in the Gradle output

Comment: Generally speaking, this post goes over how to find your error message.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698816/gradle-what-is-a-non-zero-exit-value-and-how-do-i-fix-it