# java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1 android studio

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to run my application but it is giving above mentioned error. Unable to find solution. Kindly help. Following is my Gradle code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mabdullahali.trenditch"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle - What is a non-zero exit value and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698816/gradle-what-is-a-non-zero-exit-value-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Add dexOptions in gradle.
Hope this will help you .let me know.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mabdullahali.trenditch"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental = true;
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize = "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the value

```
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
```

to

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

or installed Build Tool version seen in SDK Manager