# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' after cleaning project

Tags: android, xml, gradle

The error I've been getting is this:

```
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\bliss_000\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\bliss_000\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:207)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\bliss_000\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:43)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:983)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:163)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\bliss_000\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:367)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:41)
    ... 80 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.468 secs
```

Along with this, Android Studio can't resolve R class. By the way, I don't really know how to post errors on here properly, so I just used a snippet. I already tried cleaning the build and rebuilding it, nothing from previous posts and solutions have worked.

The following is my Android Manifest file if you were wondering, I don't mind posting any resource files or classes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bliss_000.todolistapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        name="com.example.bliss_000.todolistapp.AppController"
        android:name="com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.bliss_000.todolistapp.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.bliss_000.todolistapp.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.bliss_000.todolistapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.bliss_000.todolistapp.GoalsActivity"
            android:label="Craft"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.bliss_000.todolistapp.GoalsEditorActivity"
            android:label="Craft"
            android:launchmode="singleTop" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It could also be something wrong with a resource file, I really don't know how I would be able to find it without taking apart the entire project.

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project

Comment: I've already cleaned and rebuilt the project, none of it is working.

Comment: have you all dependency same version ? Show your gradle

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1

Comment: @Nepster - No, please see the Gradle task this question failed on. Compare the steps after the words `Execution failed for task` that one is about pre-dexing, this one is about resources

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Keyword is **Resources** from

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'
```

Therefore, the problem likely exists somewhere in an XML file.

For instance, your manifest's `application` tag. I don't think [that `name` attribute is valid](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html). Plus, you already have `android:name` for a different class. Therefore remove the `name` one. Or change to `android:name` and keep only one. If you need both classes, then have AppController extend the BootstrapApplication class.

```
<application
    name="com.example.bliss_000.todolistapp.AppController"
```

Also, the entire package name isn't necessary.

For example, the MainActivity can simply be

```
<activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
```

Comment: I'm using the volley library so I need to have AppController in the application name, it's just something that's required. Also, I only added ".AppController", not the entire name, it just auto completes it for me.

Comment: You can only have one `android:name`. You do not **need** AppController for Volley. If you do need it, and don't otherwise know your way around the problem then remove `BootstrapApplication`. The root problem is the `name` attribute is not valid there

Comment: I forgot to mention that the android manifest I posted wasn't the original code, it's just what came up in a tab that was debug/AndroidManifest.xml. I'll just use this answer anyways and look through my resource files since I have 6 files in layout for recyclerviews and activity design.

Comment: Alright, best of luck. You could try the `lint` task, as I describe here (just after the Android Studio image) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698816/gradle-what-is-a-non-zero-exit-value-and-how-do-i-fix-it/36698817#36698817

Comment: Yeah, lint task didn't help. I ended up taking out all the launchmodes, labels and windowsoftinputs out of the android manifest after testing out all the other resource layout files in another project. It finally worked afterwards. I don't even know what any of those do yet, I was just using a tutorial as reference but the program is still working fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

For me it was to update the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in `build.gradle` from 27 to 28.

Answer (score 1):

90% possible your problem is from xml files

**Check following things in your xml**

- Go to xml -> find (ctrl +f)-> search "@string/" -> check all strings are valid
- do the same thing for "@drawable/" & "@color/"

In my case I missed some drawables & colors and some strings were not mapping

String not mapping issue

ex: "@string/password" "password" string available in my **strings.xml** but when I click (ctrl +click) not open in strings.xml

I hardcode the not mapped strings.. problem fixed

Answer (score 0):

This problem may caused from *xml* code content:

1. Check `activity_main.xml` for all errors,
2. Fix all errors than rebuild by going to menu->build than click on 'Rebuild Project'

Answer (score 0):

I'll add on that to check **EVERY** `.xml` file. This includes your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Most errors can also be subtle, too. For example, this piece of code was causing the error: `android:fullBackupContent=""`. In case if you can't find the error, try using `gradlew build --stacktrace`, as it gives a full stacktrace, allowing for you to trace the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue why this is happening
It because of XML file only

**Solution:**

In You project
go to android folder-> app -> app -> src -> main -> res -> drawable -> launch_background.xml

Their replace this Default Code inside of `<''>`

```
item android:drawable="@android:color/white"
```

Save and run the app

Answer (score 0):

What I did and helps me was change the old package name.

For exemple lets suppose that your package was "us.com.app-old-name" and you for some reason changed for "br.com.cooler-name".

What was happening was that some files were with "us.com.app-old-name" when they should have "br.com.cooler-name"

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue in my app because I wanted to merge with my workmate branch. I noticed the issue was with something related with xml resources so 
what worked for me was;

- Download the zip project from Github with his branch
- Unzip the project
- Copy the entire drawable folder to my drawable folder
- Avoid the double xml of course
- Make & Rebuild Project